# Is it possible to create Thiessen polygons around nodes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

Is it possible to create Thiessen polygons around nodes in QGIS? e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you'll find "Voronoi Polygons" in Vector - Geometry tools. Additionally, you can access the QGIS and GRASS Voronoi implementation in the Processing Toolbox

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The [ftools plugin](http://www.ftools.ca/) can produce Thiessen polygons, as Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Delaunay Triangulation.