# How to use ST_DelaunayTriangles to construct a Voronoi diagram?

Tags: postgis, sql, voronoi-thiessen

(edit 2019) [ST_VoronoiPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_VoronoiPolygons.html) available **since PostGIS v2.3**!

---

With PostGIS 2.1+ we can use [ST_DelaunayTriangles()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DelaunayTriangles.html) to generate a [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), that is a [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of its [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), and, in theory, they have an exact and reversible conversion.

Does any safe  **SQL-standard script** with [an optimized algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm) exist for *this PostGIS2  Delaunay-to-Voronoi conversion*?

---

Other refs: [1](http://www.graphicsgroups.com/5-graphics-algorithms/28052eeb7ee160f1.htm), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85484/287948)

Comment: Is https://gist.github.com/djq/4714788 the sort of thing you are after?

Comment: I think he wants a purely SQL implementation using ST_DelaunayTriangles()

Comment: [See this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116677/7505) to install `ST_DelaunayTriangles` in Linux [Debian Stable](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/).

Comment: **! [ST_VoronoiPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_VoronoiPolygons.html) available since PostGIS 2.3**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following query appears to do a reasonable set of voronoi polygons starting from the Delaunay Triangles.

I'm not a big Postgres user, so it can probably be improved quite a bit.

```
WITH 
    -- Sample set of points to work with
    Sample AS (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT (12 5, 5 7, 2 5, 19 6, 19 13, 15 18, 10 20, 4 18, 0 13, 0 6, 4 1, 10 0, 15 1, 19 6)') geom),
    -- Build edges and circumscribe points to generate a centroid
    Edges AS (
    SELECT id,
        UNNEST(ARRAY['e1','e2','e3']) EdgeName,
        UNNEST(ARRAY[
            ST_MakeLine(p1,p2) ,
            ST_MakeLine(p2,p3) ,
            ST_MakeLine(p3,p1)]) Edge,
        ST_Centroid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Union(-- Done this way due to issues I had with LineToCurve
            ST_CurveToLine(REPLACE(ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(ST_MakeLine(p1,p2),ST_MakeLine(p2,p3)))),'LINE','CIRCULAR'),15),
            ST_CurveToLine(REPLACE(ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(ST_MakeLine(p2,p3),ST_MakeLine(p3,p1)))),'LINE','CIRCULAR'),15)
        ))) ct      
    FROM    (
        -- Decompose to points
        SELECT id,
            ST_PointN(g,1) p1,
            ST_PointN(g,2) p2,
            ST_PointN(g,3) p3
        FROM    (
            SELECT (gd).Path id, ST_ExteriorRing((gd).Geom) g -- ID andmake triangle a linestring
            FROM (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(geom))) gd FROM Sample) a -- Get Delaunay Triangles
            )b
        ) c
    )
SELECT ST_Polygonize(ST_Node(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(v, ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(v))))))
FROM (
    SELECT  -- Create voronoi edges and reduce to a multilinestring
        ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(ST_MakeLine(
        x.ct,
        CASE 
        WHEN y.id IS NULL THEN
            CASE WHEN ST_Within(
                x.ct,
                (SELECT ST_ConvexHull(geom) FROM sample)) THEN -- Don't draw lines back towards the original set
                -- Project line out twice the distance from convex hull
                ST_MakePoint(ST_X(x.ct) + ((ST_X(ST_Centroid(x.edge)) - ST_X(x.ct)) * 2),ST_Y(x.ct) + ((ST_Y(ST_Centroid(x.edge)) - ST_Y(x.ct)) * 2))
            END
        ELSE 
            y.ct
        END
        ))) v
    FROM    Edges x 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN -- Self Join based on edges
        Edges y ON x.id <> y.id AND ST_Equals(x.edge,y.edge)
    ) z;
```

This produces the following set of polygons for the sample points included in the query [image]

### Query Explanation

#### Step 1

Create the Delaunay Triangles from the input geometries

```
SELECT (gd).Path id, ST_ExteriorRing((gd).Geom) g -- ID and make triangle a linestring
FROM (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(geom))) gd FROM Sample) a -- Get Delaunay Triangles
```

#### Step 2

Decompose the triangle nodes and make edges can be made.  I think there should be a better way to get the edges, but I didn't find one.

```
SELECT ...
        ST_MakeLine(p1,p2) ,
        ST_MakeLine(p2,p3) ,
        ST_MakeLine(p3,p1)
        ...
FROM    (
    -- Decompose to points
    SELECT id,
        ST_PointN(g,1) p1,
        ST_PointN(g,2) p2,
        ST_PointN(g,3) p3
    FROM    (
        ... Step 1...
        )b
    ) c
```

[image]

#### Step 3

Build the circumscribed circles for each triangle and find the centroid

```
SELECT ... Step 2 ...
    ST_Centroid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Union(-- Done this way due to issues I had with LineToCurve
        ST_CurveToLine(REPLACE(ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(ST_MakeLine(p1,p2),ST_MakeLine(p2,p3)))),'LINE','CIRCULAR'),15),
        ST_CurveToLine(REPLACE(ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(ST_MakeLine(p2,p3),ST_MakeLine(p3,p1)))),'LINE','CIRCULAR'),15)
    ))) ct      
FROM    (
    -- Decompose to points
    SELECT id,
        ST_PointN(g,1) p1,
        ST_PointN(g,2) p2,
        ST_PointN(g,3) p3
    FROM    (
        ... Step 1...
        )b
    ) c
```

[image]

The `Edges` CTE outputs each edge and the id(path) of the triangle it belongs to.

#### Step 4

'Outer Join' the 'Edges' table to itself where there are equal edges for different triangles (interior edges).

```
SELECT  
    ...
    ST_MakeLine(
    x.ct, -- Circumscribed Circle centroid
    CASE 
    WHEN y.id IS NULL THEN
        CASE WHEN ST_Within( -- Don't draw lines back towards the original set
            x.ct,
            (SELECT ST_ConvexHull(geom) FROM sample)) THEN
            -- Project line out twice the distance from convex hull
            ST_MakePoint(
                ST_X(x.ct) + ((ST_X(ST_Centroid(x.edge)) - ST_X(x.ct)) * 2),
                T_Y(x.ct) + ((ST_Y(ST_Centroid(x.edge)) - ST_Y(x.ct)) * 2)
            )
        END
    ELSE 
        y.ct -- Centroid of triangle with common edge
    END
    ))) v
FROM    Edges x 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN -- Self Join based on edges
    Edges y ON x.id <> y.id AND ST_Equals(x.edge,y.edge)
```

Where there is a common edge draw a line between the respective centroids

[image]

Where the edge is not joined (exterior) draw a line from the centroid through the centre of the edge.  Only do this if the centroid of the circle is inside the set of triangles.

[image]

#### Step 5

Get the convex hull for the drawn lines as a line.  Union up and merge all the lines.  Node the line set so that we have a topological set that can be polygonized.

```
SELECT ST_Polygonize(ST_Node(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(v, ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(v))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Good clue, perhaps a solution (!). I need to test, but can't now... Analysing: you use `ST_ConvexHull` and `ST_Centroid` instead "perpendicular bisectors" as in the direct algorithm suggested by my [ref1/Kenneth Sloa](http://www.graphicsgroups.com/5-graphics-algorithms/28052eeb7ee160f1.htm)... Why not the direct solution?

Comment: I pretty much are doing perpendicular bisectors for the exterior edges, just without all the math:)  I'll add an explanation of the steps I took to the answer

Comment: Good illustrations and explanation, ***very didactic!***     You posted all that I need (!), but this days I not have Postgis2.1 to test... Can I check here (as comment) some questions that any one can answer by testing?       **1)** the ST_Polygonize "creates a GeometryCollection containing possible polygons", they are all the Voronoi cells, correct?        **2)** about performance, you think your centroid-based solution have similar CPU-time than  "all the math of perpendicular bisectors calculation"?

Comment: @PeterKrauss 1) ST_polygonize does create the voronoi cells from the line work.  The trick with it is to make sure all the line work is split at the nodes. 2) I don't think there would be a lot of difference between calculating the bisection and using ST_Centroid on the line.  But it would need to be tested.

Comment: [See this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116677/7505) to install `ST_DelaunayTriangles` in Linux [Debian Stable](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/).

Comment: One of the most genius answers I have ever seen, and you start by saying I'm not a big Postgis user. I only wish I could upvote you more.

Comment: I've tried to use this beautiful answer, I  changed the first with statemaent to with Sample as (SELECT st_collect("geometry field") as geom FROM public.my_old_table) and then I had to add an st_setsrid on the ST_MakePoint in the last select statement. My problem is however that I have 100 000+ points so the question takes extremely long time to process, any ideas how to speed it up?

Comment: It would probably be best to use the [builtin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DelaunayTriangles.html) that exists now.  Other than that, break it into steps and tune each step.  It is worth noting [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/172198/36484) as it shows a flaw it the process above for certain sets of data