# Using postgis to flatten all polygons in table

Tags: postgis, union, intersect

I have a table with many polygons. The polygons all have a name and a value.

I want to flatten these polygons so that each polygon border remains as border to the resulting polygons. Instead of having a stack of polygons I will remain with a mosaic of polygons based on the same lines.

[image: A stack of polygons]

Resulting in this:

[image]

The names are insignificant. I want to sum the values of each original polygon within the different tiles of the mosaic. The number of overlaps would also be relevant to calculate.

I am looking for a solution using PostGIS. I have solved this using FME, but my data size (20.000+ objects with millions of overlaps) makes this too time consuming. The [union function in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisunion) does this fairly straightforward as illustrated form their document webpages.

[image: Figure on QGIS union from the QGIS webpage]

For those in need of a context the data is actually multi-ring buffers around seabird nesting sites in Norway. The data sets are per species and we are looking at several thousands nesting sites per species.

You may download a test data set [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrkc24ev3hqnvv7/polytest.7z?dl=1).

Comment: Does ST_Union without a GROUP BY work?

Comment: @DPSSpatial no, I have been testing on the above pictured dataset. I should ideally get 7 individual tiles.

Comment: hmmm not sure about this, had some ideas but not working... hope someone can chime in as this seems easy!

Comment: FME has a similar functionality called AreaOnAreaOverlayer

Comment: Are you sure that works on 1 input table? Seems by the documentation that's doing a combination of intersects /clips on mutiple inputs...

Comment: @DPSSpatial yes, single geometry is ok. But works as a full dissolve. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html

Comment: Hello I'm also working in the same thing. If you find the answer, please post it here. What I did until now was getting the intersections with the following sql statement :
SELECT ST_INTERSECTION(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM yourtable t1, yourtable t2 WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID AND ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom); 
This gives you all the intersections, however with a overlapping between them. So I think we need to overlap between them again and add in the end the parts out of the intersection with "ST_Difference(original_dataset, intersected_dataset)". I think this would be a start for you two.

Comment: @ragnvald could you create thiessen/delauney triangles around the sites instead? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114764/how-to-use-st-delaunaytriangles-to-construct-a-voronoi-diagram#115729

Comment: since PostGIS 2.5, `ST_Split` supports splitting *Polygon* by *MultiLinestring*; if that's applicable, collect the exterior rings as blade, split all polygons and count equals. distinct and join those with the original table to sum up the attributes. if you join/collect/split by intersection (bbox intersection, even), performance might be alright.

Comment: Fair enough @ThingumaBob but I need to do this on all objects at the same time. Since this is a list of objects (geoms) I need to collect all of them (polygons) into one multipolygon to create the MultiLineString before following your advice. Simply doing this for each object will deliver a copy of each object. Ie not moving forward at all. So how can I itarate throgh all objects and pull out multipolygons?

Comment: The following SQL-query will split the test data set into 7 parts. After that one will have to poll values from intersecting polygons and add them. SQL-query: 
 CREATE TABLE tbl_multigeom AS
 SELECT geom FROM ST_Dump((
    SELECT ST_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
        SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
            SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(geom) AS the_geom FROM tbl_inn) AS lines
        ) AS noded_lines
    )
)

Comment: Help with an upvote for finding a solution for the answer similar to yours:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301296/how-to-recursively-loop-through-parent-polygons-intersections-to-get-smallest-c

Answer (score 2):

Download the PostGIS Addons from this link: https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons

Install by running the postgis_addons.sql file.

Test by running the postgis_addons_test.sql file.

Here is a self contained example of a problem similar to your one:

```
WITH geomtable AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0), (0.2 0.5, 0.2 1.5, 0.8 1.5, 0.8 0.5, 0.2 0.5))') geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 0.2, 1 1, 3 1, 3 0.2, 1 0.2))') geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1.5 0.8, 1.5 1.2, 2.5 1.2, 2.5 0.8, 1.5 0.8))') geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 id, ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((3 0, 3 2, 5 2, 5 0, 3 0)), ((4 3, 4 4, 5 4, 5 3, 4 3)))') geom
)
SELECT a.id, unnest(ST_SplitAgg(a.geom, b.geom, 0.00001)) geom
FROM geomtable a,
     geomtable b
WHERE ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) OR
      ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom) OR
      ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) OR
      ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

In your query, just replace geomtable with your table:

```
SELECT a.id, unnest(ST_SplitAgg(a.geom, b.geom, 0.00001)) geom
FROM polytest a,
     polytest b
WHERE ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) OR
      ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom) OR
      ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) OR
      ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Should work for thousands of polygons and when there are more than two overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can go by parts...
Use the approach mentioned before:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_intersection AS
SELECT
    ST_INTERSECTION(t1.geom, t2.geom) as geom
FROM original_dataset t1, original_dataset t2 
WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID AND ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom);
```

And then you use the previous table and the original dataset to run the [ST_Difference](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) (The order is important in this case) between then. It should put you on the track

```
SELECT
    ST_Difference(t2.geom, t1.geom) AS geom
FROM
  original_dataset t1, tbl_intersection t2
```

Comment: Not there quite yet. In the first query on the third line it should perhaps be "ST_INTERSECTION(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS geom"? When I remove the condition "t1.id > t2.id and" I got nine unique objects. It does however fail to isolate more than two overlaps at a time. Remember the case involve tens if  not hundreds of overlaps. I am looking for all possible pieces in the mosaic - flattended with no overlaps. Much like the QGIS sample above.

Answer (score 0):

If you've added all the correct indexes (on the ID as well as GIST index on geom), the following should do the job - as long as your server is up to spec;

```
   select st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
   from table a, table b
   where st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
   group by st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Comment: Otherwise - try something like in this article: https://postgis.net/2014/03/14/tip_intersection_faster/

Comment: Not too bad. The above one comes up with nine individual objects. So it splits them totally which is good. But I would also like to keep a select attribute and summarize an integer value in the overlapping polygons. So we are moving forward for sure. I should mention in my case I do not have two different tables, but one. Inputting the same table in your SQL query is what I did.

Comment: Great, yes you should be able to amend the query to include summing of integers. Yes table a and table b are meant to be the same. Good luck!

Comment: After further testing your suggestion seems not to produce the required outcome. So we're back at square one.

Comment: Oh dear - what is it missing?

Comment: @ragnvald ha I got to this point too - not sure why this is so difficult...