# Changing QGIS Symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm trying to change the symbol from 'marker' to 'fill' in layer properties.  Is it possible to change that so I can fill the entire property instead of having points for each property?
[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture will help

Comment: It sounds like you have points and want to see a polygon... is this right? If this is so you will need to create a minimum bounding polygon like a convex hull https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/convexhull.html

Comment: The thing is, I need the polygon to fill the exact dimensions of each property.

Comment: Select the parcels by location http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis to get your polygons... assuming your points are accurate enough.

Comment: The following link might help you - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/converting-point-sets-to-polygon-boundaries