# Creating boundary for multiple point shapefiles that overlay base polygon shapefile?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, point-in-polygon, geometry-conversion

I have several point .shp files that were geocoded using OpenStreetMap. I located a base map to overlay the point files. I would like to create an artificial boundary based on an 80/20 rule for each point file. For example, the boundary would be drawn around 80% of the points and this process would follow for the rest of the point .shp files that have been geocoded. I searched through previous post and found [Converting point sets to polygon boundaries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/converting-point-sets-to-polygon-boundaries). This response represents what I would like to achieve. Therefore I attempted the procedures and fail short of the goal of obtaining arbitrary boundaries that would overlay. I have attached an image for a visual?

I am after any insight on how to create artificial boundaries based off an 80/20 rule.

I am new user to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: When you say that you tried what was referenced in the other post, what failed? Did you receive an error message?

Comment: In the other post I followed item number 12, I was able to create the Voronoi plogyons but it distorted the base map. Therefore, I followed the comments to clip but the boundary lines from the Voronoi plogyons disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Concave Hull (QGIS plugin) for the outer polygon. Calculate the distance from each point to the Outer polygon. Sort the Points by distance, deleting the smallest 20%. Generate a new Concave Hull around the remaining 80%.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using the 2.8 and received an error stating "invalid or have unfulfilled dependencies" and "The plugin is broken/ Python said: cannot import".

Comment: The Convex Hull tool is part of Core QGIS, Vector, Geoprocessing Tools. Perhaps try it instead.