# Split multi-geometries polygons

Tags: qgis, algorithm, multi-geometry

Is there is a way in QGIS (or SQL, ArcMap) to split multi-geometries in polygons automatically. I could do this manually (split features, split multi-part to single-part etc...), but this would just be so time consuming. Here's a visual of what I'm wanting the polygons to look like:
[image: Bad Polygon 1]

[image: Good Polygon 2]

As you can see **polygon 2** has been broken up into 5 polygons instead of being a single polygon in **polygon 1**. I tried what this person has done in SQL [HERE](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/splitting-multi-geometries-into-single-geometries/), but then that would only break **polygon 1** into three polygons still having a multi-geometry polygon.

Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: The easy part is to explode the members of multipolygon into simple polygons, but how would you define the logic with splitting the ring shaped polygon into three?

Comment: @underdark thank you for your reply, but I ended up figuring it out by my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So my answer was similar to this problem [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/converting-point-sets-to-polygon-boundaries).

My solution was to first:

1. Extract nodes from polygon layer.
2. Perform delaunay triangulation on node layer.
3. Perform a Symmetrical Difference in the geoprocessing tools with your triangulation layer as your input layer and your over-lapping layer as the difference layer.