# Clipping interpolated raster with shape of original point data-set

Tags: raster, qgis-3, clip, interpolation

I have a point dataset with XYZ values.

I inserted this layer in QGIS 3.6 via `layer > add layer > add delimited layer`.

Then, I interpolated these points to a raster via `interpolation > TIN interpolation`.

However, now the data are interpolated over the whole domain, even in areas where no data are present in the original file. How can I clip out the interpolated raster with the original shape of the point dataset?

The xyz file can be downloaded from:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4ae4ce51072dceef93486314d161509920191021213532/48e4ee68c17269bd6f7a72c1384b3c9a20191021213532/60b04d

Interpolated raster:

[image: example1]

Interpolated raster with original point dataset on top:

[image: example2]

Comment: `Points to Polygon` then apply `Inverted polygons` to it further put over the raster

Comment: @Taras. Hi thanks. Where is the points to polygon tool? Does it need to be downloaded somewhere?

Comment: I think there are several possibilities to accomplish this, by means of a plugin [Point to Polygon](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/PointToPolygon/), as well check this article [Converting point sets to polygon boundaries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/converting-point-sets-to-polygon-boundaries).

Comment: By the way which projection is that? Is it `EPSG:4176`?

Comment: I think it also possible with a different approach: what if you find a shapefile of Antarctica in exactly the same shape and just overlap it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this is how I got a polygon shape file from the original point dataset:

1. **Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Buffer**: set a buffer value so that the polygons will cover the whole area.
2. **Vector Geoprocessing tools > Dissolve**: so that all the individual polygons become a single one.
3. **Optional: Vector > Greoprocessing tools > Buffer**: to add a negative buffer so that the final polygon's boundaries as as close to the original points as possible.