# How to Spatial Join centroids of parcels to point data and get the distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-join

I'm currently using ArcMap 10.1 (basic license). I have a LSOA shape file of Camden borough. From there I added 2 extra fields within the attribute table, X and Y. I then calculated the 2 extra fields to give me the centroid of each output area. I also have a point data shape file of the underground stations within Camden borough. three things I need to work out:

1. Get the **distance** for every LSOA to the closest underground stations in order to create a choropleth map
2. I need to create a polygon vector file containing the catchment areas of every underground station in Camden. If there are 19 stations then I assuming that there are 19
    catchments areas
3. Get the centroid of the catchment areas and then get the distance to the closest underground stations and create a choropleth map

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Can you include a link for or definition of LSOA, please?  Also, this looks like 3 questions in one Question and I think the Q&A format of GIS SE works best with [**one question per Question**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: the link for the definition of LSOA
http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/Info.do?m=0&s=1386848570115&enc=1&page=nessgeography/superoutputareasexplained/output-areas-explained.htm&nsjs=true&nsck=false&nssvg=false&nswid=1129

Answer (score 1):

For getting feature to feature distance you may use the [ET GeoWizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/) (within ArcMap) Point Distance or Closest Feature Distances tools.

Comment: is that a free download?

Comment: Yes, most of the tools you may use for free (yes, free download).

Comment: I will try that tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats all very basic GIS functionality (if I understood your requirements right), unfortunately ArcGIS Basic is especially for point 2. very restricted to do those:

1. Assuming you want the distance from the LSOA centroid point to the nearest underground station point, you just have to right click the LSOA centroid layer > Join and Relates > Join

   - Select "Join data from another layer based on spatial location"
   - Select the underground station layer
   - Select "Each point will be given all the attributes ... in the layer ... that is closest to it, **and a distance field showing how close that point is**" (the second radio button)
   - Select a destination FeatureClass
   - (Alternatively you can use the GP Tool for spatial joining, which is the same functionality)
2. I think the simplest method (don't know if it is accurate enough for you) is to calculate [Thiessen polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001m000000) from the station points. Unfortunately you need ArcGIS Desktop Advanced for this. Optionally you can use [QGIS to create a voronoi map/thiessen polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/is-it-possible-to-create-thiessen-polygons-around-nodes-in-qgis)
3. The same procedure as you did with the LSOA polygons, I guess