# Creating a surface of zones of high,medium and low intensity based on an attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, interpolation, heat-map

I have a point shapefile having attribute of fire probability in the range of 0,1,2,3.
0 = zero probability
1 = low probability
2 = medium probability
3 = high probability

Only 2 points have 0 values, very fever points with low, most of the points with medium probability and second highest number of points with high probability.

[image]

From this I want to create a continuous zonal map showing areas with high,medium and low probability.

[image: Points in red have 3 value, points in yellow have medium value and rest in green]

I've tried many interpolation tools in arcmap but none is giving me desired results.It should take into consideration the point density first and further classify it on the basis of fire probability attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use the Create Thiessen Polygons tool.  The resulting polygons will define all the areas closest to each point.  The resulting polygons will be populated with the attributes from the points so you can symbolize or query the polygons by fire probability, or further process the data based on the attributes. You will need an advanced ArcGIS license to use this tool. [Here is a link to the tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/business-analyst-toolbox/thiessen-polygons.htm).  If you do not have an Advanced ArcGIS license you can create the polygons for free [using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/is-it-possible-to-create-thiessen-polygons-around-nodes-in-qgis).