# Rasterize using irregular points as centroids for each cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6

I have a dataframe (xyz), which I loaded in ArcGIS using add xyz-files, saved it as a new shapefile. The distance between the points is irregular. I want to rasterize the pointshape with each point as centroid in the equivalent cell.

I thought the conversion-tool: point to raster would do this automatically. But it does not give me the result I was looking for.

Example result:[image]

I defined the cell size as: 9950,9950
CRS is: WGS_1984_UTM_32N

ArcGIS version 10.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create Theissen polygons around your point data.  Then, if you need them to be rasterized, rasterize them to a dataset with a fine spatial resolution.
Here is a link to [Thiessen Polyons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/business-analyst-toolbox/thiessen-polygons.htm).
And conversion from [Polygon to raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm).

These tools require more ESRI advanced license levels and toolboxes that you may not have.  If that is the case, look to QGIS  to accomplish the same tasks. See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/is-it-possible-to-create-thiessen-polygons-around-nodes-in-qgis) and [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html).

Comment: do you see any way to do this in R?

Comment: @Bari  I am not an R guy but I found this R function to create Voronoi polygons which is the same thing as a Theissen polygon. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SDraw/versions/2.1.8/topics/voronoi.polygons and this  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/rasterize

Answer (score 2):

### Simple answer

You can't

### Long answer

A raster is basically an image composed by pixels. Each pixel must have the same resolution (size) as all other pixels in the image. Also, they are placed in a regular grid made by rows and columns.

As such, you cannot have in the same image pixels that are not placed exactly inside this grid and which are not side by side with the neighboring pixels (**with no overlap**).

What you are asking would violate these concepts, as your points are placed irregularly and so each pixel would be placed in the final raster regardless of the underline grid.

Comment: @umbre1987 thanks for your help. I changed the cell size by try and error since every point lay in a pixel. Even they are not centroids, I can continue working.